# Statsmodels : change variable name/label in the output

Tags: python, statsmodels

When using Statsmodels while defining the reference level of a categorical variables under the R-style formula framework, the name of the variable in the output is quite big, for instance :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
sm.Logit.from_formula("y~ c(my_variable, ,Treatment(reference= 'reference_level')) "
```

will output

```
C(x,Treatment(reference='reference_level'))[some_value]
```

as the variable name in the model summary.

How can I rename this output label to something more readable without chaining the variable name ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Under the hood, the formula api uses [Patsy](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/categorical-coding.html) to apply your formula string to your data. The long names come from this process.

A quick fix is when you call `summary()`, you can optionally include an `xname` argument. `xname` is a list of labels that are applied to each row of the summary's coef table. The length of `xname` must be the same length as the `params` attribute on your `Result` (the object returned by `fit()`).

```py
fit = sm.Logit.from_formula("variable ~ C(type,Treatment(reference= 'B'))",data=data).fit()
fit.summary(xname=["label 1", "label 2", "label 3", "etc."])
```

Take a look at the [Summary object](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model.LogitResults.summary.html) for more customizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.Categorical` to set the levels. The reference will come first. For example in the below dataset, `reference = 'B'` :

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(222)
data  = pd.DataFrame({'variable':np.random.randint(0,2,100),
                      'type': np.random.choice(['A','B','C'],100)
                     })

fit = sm.Logit.from_formula("variable ~ C(type,Treatment(reference= 'B'))",data=data).fit()
fit.summary()

                                         coef   std err z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
Intercept                               0.1542  0.393   0.392   0.695   -0.617  0.925
C(type, Treatment(reference='B'))[T.A] -0.4261  0.515   -0.828  0.408   -1.435  0.583
C(type, Treatment(reference='B'))[T.C]  0.2288  0.517   0.443   0.658   -0.784  1.241
```

And if you use pd.Categorical, you get the same result:

```
data['type'] = pd.Categorical(data['type'],categories=['B','A','C'],ordered=True)
fit = sm.Logit.from_formula("variable ~ type",data=data).fit()
fit.summary()

             coef   std err z   P>|z|   [0.025  0.975]
Intercept   0.1542  0.393   0.392   0.695   -0.617  0.925
type[T.A]   -0.4261 0.515   -0.828  0.408   -1.435  0.583
type[T.C]   0.2288  0.517   0.443   0.658   -0.784  1.241
```